# How to inject a variable into a Django template's context, similar to the 'as' argument of the built-in 'url' tag?

Tags: python, django

According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url, it is possible to define a URL to be retrieved later like so:

```
{% url 'some-url-name' arg arg2 as the_url %}

<a href="{{ the_url }}">I'm linking to {{ the_url }}</a>
```

Following https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/snippet/2016/08/22/dealing-with-querystring-parameters.html, I've defined a tag `relative_url` as follows:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.http import urlencode
from django.http import QueryDict

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def relative_url(field_name, value, query_string=None):
    url = urlencode({field_name: value})
    if query_string:
        query_dict = QueryDict(query_string, mutable=True)
        query_dict[field_name] = value
        url = query_dict.urlencode()
    return '?' + url
```

I would like to make this tag work with `as` similar to the built-in `url` tag, so that I can do

```
{% with params=request.GET.urlencode %}
  {% relative_url field value params as action_url %}
{% endwith %}
```

and thereafter refer to it like

```
<form action="{{ action_url }}"> ... </form>
```

I'm looking at the Django source code for the `url` tag at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaulttags.py, but I'm finding it not so easy to comprehend.

What I suspect I need to do is instead of return the string, return a `URLNode`, like

```
return URLNode(viewname, args, kwargs, asvar)
```

where `asvar` is the variable being injected into the context, but I'm unsure what to fill in for each constructor argument. Is there a simple way to inject a variable into the context in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You literally don't need to do anything: this functionality is built into the  `simple_tag` decorator. Just use it the way you show in that example.

See the last paragraph of the [`simple_tag` section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) of the docs.